# GCM onMessage never called. Is it due to blocked ports? how to find?

Tags: android, port, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM for android push notifications. I can able to register with GCM and get a registration id in android. That means the ports 5228,5229 or 5230 either one of those must be open to receive the registration id right? Hence can we say that the blocking of the ports is not a problem ?I am sending the registration id to server side and that is received. The message is sent to from server side app.

But it is not received by the android app. The onMessage in `GCMIntentService` is never called. Please tell me the possible reasons why message is not received. How can I check if the message is received by GCM servers ? Is Port blocking a problem? if so how to identify and rectify it?

I tried telnet localhost 5228 in cmd, which responded as connection cant be open on port 5228. connect failed. Does that mean that the port 5228 is blocked ?

When sending message from server app, I get result with a not null message id and null error code. that means the message is delivered, right?

server side code

```
@WebServlet("/GCMNotification")
public class GCMNotification extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  // Put your Google API Server Key here
  private static final String GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY = "AIzaSyAJBGj_8aaNykTNaPxdayggDMyxzArE7gM";
  static final String MESSAGE_KEY = "message";  

  public GCMNotification() {
    super();
  }

  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);

  }

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    Result result = null;

    String share = request.getParameter("shareRegId");

    // GCM RedgId of Android device to send push notification
    String regId = "";
    if (share != null && !share.isEmpty()) {
      regId = request.getParameter("regId");
      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("GCMRegId.txt");
      writer.println(regId);
      writer.close();
      request.setAttribute("pushStatus", "GCM RegId Received.");
      request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp")
          .forward(request, response);
    } else {

      try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "GCMRegId.txt"));
        regId = br.readLine();
        br.close();
        String userMessage = request.getParameter("message");
        Sender sender = new Sender(GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY);
        Message message = new Message.Builder().timeToLive(30)
            .delayWhileIdle(false).addData(MESSAGE_KEY, userMessage).build();
        System.out.println("regId: " + regId);
        result = sender.send(message, regId, 1);
        if(result.getMessageId()==null)
        {
            System.out.println("error"+result.getErrorCodeName());
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("msg created"+result.getCanonicalRegistrationId());
            if(result.getCanonicalRegistrationId()==null)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("not null");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("pushStatus: "+result.getMessageId()+"\n"+result.getErrorCodeName()+"\n"+result.toString());
        request.setAttribute("pushStatus", result.toString());
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        request.setAttribute("pushStatus",
            "RegId required: " + ioe.toString());
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        request.setAttribute("pushStatus", e.toString());
      }
      request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp")
          .forward(request, response);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: post the server side code(exp:php)

Comment: i think you have problem in server key, refer this http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/

Comment: @appu bala- Thanks..! I created the server key and tried which dint work. so i regenerated the key, still the problem persists.

Comment: hi bro i think your error,google console need to allow your server to access gcm,so  in server key generation you need to give your ipaddress,to know your ip,type "whats my ip" in google,copy that and put in server key

Comment: @Appu bala- if i dont give a IP, it will allow all the IP address right? initially i had 0.0.0.0/0 then removed that ip. is that a problem. if so how to rectify it?

Comment: if you run on local means,follow the above mentioned way to get ip and put in server key generator otherwise you run on real server means give you server ip

Comment: @Appu bala- How the registration is done, is it depend on package name, should i change that as well while using new server key.?

Comment: what you ask i can't get you,create new project and follow the blog steps you get your answer

Comment: @Appu bala- I tried what u said. i get invalidrequestexception : http status code:401 at the server side. how to overcome that.